# VB.NET ADO disappearing data issue

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, ado.net, combobox

I have a bound datagridview and a dataset with tables.

I have two sets of comboboxes bound to the same field "Restaurant" in the tables (mirroring each other).

In the "NewEmployeeRestaurant" combobox I change the value and it reflects in the datagridview. I can shoot around clicking all over the datagridview on other employees, but when I return to the employee I changed, the value remains what I changed it to. All is good in the world.

However, when I go to the "EmployeeRestaurant" combobox with the same settings, I change the value and it is reflected in the datagridview. So far so good. But when I go to another employee then click back on that employee I changed, the datagridview still shows the new value but the combobox is empty! NOT COOL!

I went so far as to try to copy the combobox object that IS working and use it, but I get the same issue. I'm dumbfounded. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I have done some investigation and found that the selection in the combobox does write to the table. However, when I push the binding source back to that position (index), it wipes out the selection in the combobox! Why in the world would it do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I believe this to be some kind of bug in VS. I had a groupbox with other bound comboboxes tied to the same table. I had made the groupbox visible = false for user functionality reasons. When I defaulted that groupbox to visible = true, the original combobox worked.

I am maddened by these VS bugs but grateful for the tool in general. I hope this helps someone in the future.